# One function for multiple element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code generated n times on  my page

```html
<form class="new_comment">
   <input accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="file" 
   class="file_comment" key=comment_id type="file" name="comment[media]">
   <span class="lds-dual-ring"></span>
   <span class="valid_icon" style="display:none;"></span>
</form>
```

and i have the following jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#file').on('click touchstart' , function(){
    $(this).val('');
});

//Trigger now when you have selected any file
$("#file").change(function(e) {
  var data = new FormData();
  console.log (e.target)
  console.log(e.target.files)
  var file = e.target.files
  data.append("image", file[0]);
  $(".lds-dual-ring").css('display', 'inline-block');
  $(".valid_icon").css('display', 'none');
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
      headers: { Authorization: "Client-ID {{client-id}}" },
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".lds-dual-ring").css('display', 'none');
        $(".valid_icon").css('display', 'inline-block');
        console.log(data.data.link);
        $('#media_url').val(data.data.link);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
  })
});
});
```

This code is working well. When a user select an image from his desktop, it's uploaded on imgur and a validate icon appears.

It's working well for the first form of comment but it doesn't for the all other same form on the page.

I also have warning about non unique id, I understand why I have it but I don't know how I can have only one function or style class for an indeterminate number of form

Comment: `id` MUST be unique, consider the warning as a very important warning. Just add a common class to all elements that must have this function and then `$(".commonClass").change(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you understand why you're receiving the warning about non-unique IDs, but I'll briefly touch on it for any future viewers.

IDs (e.g., `#myId`) *must* occur only once on any page. Just like ID numbers in real life, they refer to a specific entity, and so should only represent a single element. This is also why the JavaScript selector for IDs is *singular* (`document.getElementById`).

Classes (e.g., `.myClass`), on the other hand, can occur multiple times. Like in real life, you can group similar items into classes and refer to them collectively. The selector for classes, accordingly, is *plural* (`document.getElementsByClassName`).

It looks like your code is already set up to handle classes-- you just have to change your selector. Because your file input already has a class, you can just replace the selectors that reference the input so that they refer to the `class` attribute instead of the `id`.

Try replacing `$("#file")` with `$(".file_comment")`, and it should stop giving you the warnings.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I thought the class name had to be unique too this is why I was lost on how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Id's should be unique in the DOM. I'm not sure without testing but I would try the following:

1. Add a class to the file input element lets call it file
2. Change $("#file") to $(".file")

You'll also have to change the code  $(".lds-dual-ring").css('display', 'none'); And the other lines.

Some options is to get a reference to the form element that the input was in. And then you can call $(".lds-dual-ring",form) which will scope the jquery search to look within that form.